# Assign hostnames to exposed docker ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Okay so in Vagrant/VVV you can assign different hostnames to your different projects so when you go to http://myproject-1.dev your website shows up.

This is very convenient if you are working on dozens of projects at the same time, As far as I know such thing is not possible in docker (it can't touch hosts file), **My question is, is there something similar we can do in Docker? Some automated tool maybe?**

Using docker for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames can map *many containers together*. In docker compose, there's a hostname option. But that's only within the Docker network bridge, not available to the host

Docker isn't a VM (although it runs within one in Windows).
You can edit your hosts file to have the HyperVisor available, but you're supposed to have the host ports forwarded into the container.

Use localhost, not any hostname.

If you prefer your Vagrant patterns, continue using it, but provision Docker containers from it, or use Docker Machine